# Equivalent of R's of cor.test in Python

Tags: numpy, statistics, scipy, statsmodels

Is there a way I can find the r confidence interval in Python?

In R i could do something like:

```
cor.test(m, h)

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  m and h
t = 0.8974, df = 4, p-value = 0.4202
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.6022868  0.9164582
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.4093729
```

In Python I can calculate r (cor) using:

```
r,p = scipy.stats.pearsonr(df.age, df.pets)
```

But that doesn't return the r confidence interval.

Answer (score 11):

Here's one way to calculate confidence internal

First get the correlation value (pearson's)

```
In [85]: from scipy import stats

In [86]: corr = stats.pearsonr(df['col1'], df['col2'])

In [87]: corr
Out[87]: (0.551178607008175, 0.0)
```

Use the Fisher transformation to get z

```
In [88]: z = np.arctanh(corr[0])

In [89]: z
Out[89]: 0.62007264620685021
```

And, the sigma value i.e standard error

```
In [90]: sigma = (1/((len(df.index)-3)**0.5))

In [91]: sigma
Out[91]: 0.013840913308956662
```

Get normal 95% interval probability density function for normal continuous random variable apply `two-sided` conditional formula

```
In [92]: cint = z + np.array([-1, 1]) * sigma * stats.norm.ppf((1+0.95)/2)
```

Finally take hyperbolic tangent to get interval values for 95%

```
In [93]: np.tanh(cint)
Out[93]: array([ 0.53201034,  0.56978224])
```

Comment: Thank you, that solves it. I wonder why (and if) statsmodels and/or scipy don't already provide this.

Comment: Well, I was surprised too or I haven't searched the stack well enough.

Comment: Any updates on this?  Ideally there should be a one-liner scipy function to compute this as opposed to the eight-liner method you provided above.