# python compare each point of two correlation matrix

Tags: python, matrix, statistics

I have n observation of m variables for two different groups.
I created two correlation matrices using np.corrcoeff (normalized correlation coefficients), one for each group.

I end up with 2 n X n matrices. Each square of the matrices being a mean correlation coefficient for a given group.

Then I want to compare those two matrices. 
Is there a python function to do this ? 
I would like to: 
- compare both matrices just to know if there is differences between them (overall)
- compare each square of the matrices and end up with a correlation matrix     showing the significant differences between both matrices

For the second point, I would like to do a t-test or an anova (to include additional confounding factors). The problem is that my correlation matrix are already mean so I would need to use the formula (and the standard deviation).

Is there an easy way to do this ?

Comment: How do you want to compare them? Element-wise?

Comment: Yes I would like to compare them element-wise

Comment: Matrix1 - Matrix2 then? Or maybe squared diff `np.sqrt((Matrix1**2 - Matrix2**2))`

Comment: Yes that's the idea. But I would like to have a statistical test to get a p value in order to be sure that the difference between the two matrices is statistically significant

Comment: how is the p value defined?

Comment: I don't know. I want to perform a statistical test to compare both matrices. The thing is that the two matrices that I want to compare are already means, so I could for example compute a t test if I get the standard deviation (which should be easy since my coeff. are normally distributed). To summarize, I want to compare the two matrices with a statistical test ...

Comment: I guess you should really figure out what you need. Then we can work on how to get there. Maybe calculate the mean and standard deviation of each matrix and compare them?

Comment: Thank you. I think that I would like to compare correlation in both matrix, using a fisher - z transform as proposed in the website. https://www.psychometrica.de/correlation.html#independent . But I don't understand how to reproduce this code in python

Comment: Look for example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30390476/equivalent-of-rs-of-cor-test-in-python and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109028/fishers-z-transform-in-python